# GAS UrlFetchApp can't request GAS projects

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to have a large set of Google Apps Scripts projects, and want to have a set of HTML files available to all projects. I have a core project which has the following code:

```
function doGet (e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(e.parameter.htmldoc);
}
```

Then, from another project I can just run

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/someid/dev?htmldoc=footertemplate").getContextText();
```

However, when I try to run the code to load an HTML file, what happens is it gets HTML code to login to Google:

[image]

Everyone is able to run both projects, and every prompt asking me for permission I gave permission to. If anyone is able to figure it out, I would greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT:**

I have tried this out with two other fresh projects and found that this isn't just with these two projects

Comment: What is your expected outcome? And have you managed to make this work before?

Comment: I found a solution using a library, but it doesn't solve this specific problem so I won't put the answer in. And no, I haven't been able to make it work before

Comment: What happens when you login?

Answer (score 0):

There must be an issue with your publish settings. While publish, you should get an option like "**Who has access to the app**"

If you want to access without login, then set it as "**Anyone, even anonymous**".

[image]

Comment: No, it isn't that. Everyone has access to the app.